# How to have fill-paragraph/fill-region break the line after a period?

Tags: fill-paragraph, auto-fill-mode

I'm having trouble getting Emacs to properly fill a section of text when the last word of a suitable line ends with a period. Emacs seems to think that words separated by a period (and space) are joined.

For example, if I set the fill-column to 10 and enable auto-fill-mode, and I enter this text:

```
Look up. See the sky?
```

I'd expect that emacs would break the line and it would end up...

```
Look up.
See the sky?
```

Instead, Emacs always breaks the line before the word that ends with a period.

```
Look
up. See
the sky?
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `sentence-end-double-space` set to its default value,
which is `t`.  The relevant part of the docstring:

> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means a single space does not end a sentence.
>   This is relevant for filling.  See also `sentence-end-without-period`
>   and `colon-double-space`.

That variable needs to be set to `nil` to get the
wrapping you expect.  So:

```
(setq sentence-end-double-space nil)
```

See the [manual node on Sentences](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Sentences.html) for more information.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you, this worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm referring to [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FillParagraph) to answer your question.

### Paragraph Boundaries

> By default, text-mode assumes that empty lines separate paragraphs. The boundaries of paragraphs are determined by two variables.

So the premise of your question seems to conflict with the definition of `paragraph`.

There is an example in the same page where they try to add `*`, `+`, `-` as members of bullet list and which should be treated as different paragraphs whenever the `fill-paragraph` command is called.

```
(setq paragraph-start "\f\\|[ \t]*$\\|[ \t]*[-+*] ")
```

Try if you could add your `.` (full-stop followed by two spaces) to qualify as line break at the end of the line - which will allow fill paragraph to honor `.` as line break.